# how to make discord bot save a message sent every 5-10 minuets?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(1043523838580895857)
    timewait = random.randint(300, 600) 
    await channel.send("working!")
```

Once the command "start" has been said, the bot will get the channel i want the messages to be taken from, then it'll start the 5-10 minuet timer, and then send a message saying its working.

Im trying to get it to look in the chat every 5-10 minuets, get the last sent message and then write it in a .txt file, and then repeat this.

Comment: the approach I'd take is for the bot to receive every message, record the last time a message was written to a file, and have it actually write the message to the file only when at least five minutes have passed since writing the last one. then store the tiime again

Answer (score 2):

Everytime someone asks about doing a timer - my default is always: have you heard about [`tasks`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)? Mostly cos I think they're great and they work well for these situations.

```py
# define your task class somewhere
class MessageSaver(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.message_saver.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(minutes=5)  # dw, we can change the interval later
    async def message_saver(self):
        if not self.message_saver.current_loop:
            # loop is 0 - ie we just did the `start` command
            return
        channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
        if self.message_saver.current_loop == 1:
            # after the first 5-10 minutes
            await channel.send("Working!")

        # do the rest of what you want to do here every 5 minutes


# instantiate your class somewhere too
timer = MessageSaver(client)

# then in your command - you can start the task loop
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    timewait = random.randint(300, 600)
    # set the interval to what you want it to be
    timer.message_saver.change_interval(seconds=timewait)
    # start the loop
    timer.message_saver.start()
    # make sure you reply to your command now
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Should work for what you want it to do.